# Underline/Strikeout all options in Select Element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can we Underline/Strikeout all options in select Element using Jquery.

Underline/Strikeout to element shows only selected options as underline/strikeout.
I need to show all Options as  underline/strikeout.

Example is as below:
Shows like this if i use Below HTML Code:

```
<select id="cmb1" style="width: 80px; float: left; position: absolute; top: 269px; left: 319px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: line-through; font-family: Calibri;" data-combo="simple" data-div="divcmbSetting" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-selectee focused" data-lbl="lblcmb1" data-forecolor="51,51,51" data-backcolor="255,255,255" data-font="Calibri, 12px"><option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee">1</option><option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee">2</option><option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee">3</option><option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee">4</option></select>
```

[image]

But It should be looks like

[image]

I have tried below Jquery which applies CSS to all options Even it shows in Source also but doesn't apply to Options.

JQUERY :

```
 $("#cmb1 option").each(function () {
                        $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
                    });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0a8Lbo2p/)

Comment: this just does not work with chrome

Comment: Thanks. I haven't Check in IE.  Anyway in any case does it work in Chrome ?

Comment: I could not find an example that can `do line-through` maybe you can disable?

Comment: does disabling like this `$("select option").prop("disabled", true);`  works?

Comment: No. It's not working..

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you can style native select menu. But you could go with jquery-ui that has a selectmenu that's stylable. Like this:

Add span around option text:

```
 <select id="cmb1" style="width: 80px; float: left; position: absolute; top: 269px; left: 319px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: line-through; font-family: Calibri;" data-combo="simple" data-div="divcmbSetting" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-selectee focused" data-lbl="lblcmb1" data-forecolor="51,51,51" data-backcolor="255,255,255" data-font="Calibri, 12px">
<option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee"><span>1</span></option><option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee"><span>2</span></option>
<option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee"><span>3</span></option>
<option value="Off" style="text-decoration: line-through;" class="ui-selectee"><span>4</span></option>
</select>
```

Add select menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select').selectmenu();
})
```

Set css on span and li elements:

```
li, span
{
    text-decoration: line-through;

}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fy6gcvaz/

You might want to change styling of the whole thing though.